# show dialog before open a new tab with OnPageChangeListener (ViewPager)

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, android-viewpager

I am creating an android project which has CustomViewPager and Adapter. There is the code:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "TAB1", "TAB2", "TAB3", "TAB4", "TAB5"};        

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new FRAGMENT0();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new FRAGMENT1();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new FRAGMENT2();
        case 3:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new FRAGMENT3();
        case 4:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new FRAGMENT4();
    }

    return null;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabTitles[position];
}
```

}

And the viewPager:

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {
public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}
}
```

I have 5 tabs in the view Pager. My goal is that when the user is in FRAGMENT 0 and touch another tab before open the new to show alert dialog and then to navigate to selected  tab. The same thing is for FRAGMENT1. Thats it but I cant find solution for that. I was tried to make OnPageListener in the activity, to make OnPageListener in the fragments but it doesnt work. To work that logic I need to have the current page and the selected tab, but if I put the listener in the activity pager.getCurrentItem doesnt work properly. Can someone help me with some suggestions please?